# Fabricated "find references" in Visual Studio to understand Automapper config

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, automapper, intellisense

Are there extension points to add *fabricated* references into the "find references" feature?

Let's say we have two POCO's in different layers in an architecture, these are mapped with AutoMapper.

Ideally I'd like to know if a property in a class in the Domain layer is *infact* being used in the UI tier, to do so I'd normally follow references in Visual Studio.

The trouble is using automapper, it's abstracted away that the property is in use.

Ideally I'd like to "find references", so that it follows back to automapper with the understanding that an automapper config results in a in use item.

I suppose I could perhaps take automapper config and code gen what it's doing with some rosyln magic.

But it would be quite cool if intellisense / find references had some extensibility points so that a library could give it a taste of it's runtime behaviour.

EDIT:

I see it's been marked as too broad, understandably.

So to re-affirm my original question: Are there extension points within the Visual Studio SDK to manipulate the find references feature?

Comment: Alex, thanks for posting this, I am also facing the same difficulty. Did you find anything yet?

Comment: Hi @PriyankPanchal no I'm afraid not, I haven't been working with this area of the code base as much recently so haven't been able to dedicate any time to it. I wonder if *ReSharper* has any features like this, but I haven't used it for a few years.